# Is it possible to set output directory for triangle program from triangle package?

Tags: triangulation

I see no way to set destination directory or file here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.switch.html

Actually, the program places result file in the same directory, even if current directory is different.

Why? Is ti possible to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output files for the program are generated from the input file names.  You can see this from the source code on line `3586`

```
strcpy(b->outnodefilename, b->innodefilename);
...
strcat(b->outnodefilename, ".node");
strcat(b->outelefilename, ".ele");
...
```

Because of that I don't think there is a way to set the output directory as an option.  It seems you will need to manually copy the output files to a different directory

```
cp output.node your/output/dir/output.node && rm output.node
```